# Objective C: Conversion of large hex to double gives wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, decimal

I have an issue converting a big hex number 0x500123fb2d414d3d1192a659d4d39dfd to its decimal value

```
double serialNumberValue = 0;
    
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0x500123fb2d414d3d1192a659d4d39dfd"];
[scanner scanHexDouble: &serialNumberValue];

NSString* serialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.f", serialNumberValue];
NSLog(@"serialNumber decimal value : %@", serialNumber);
```

The result I get is:             106344161744262488068834846534090620928 which corresponds to 0x500123FB2D414C000000000000000000 in hex

While the correct conversion is: 106344161744262493917718975250015952381

How can i solve this issue ?

FYI: I need the last 6 digits of the hexadecimal number in its decimal value.

Comment: Try @“%.lf” - but if it doesn’t change anything my guess is NSScanner is at fault. It’s really old code developed in the 32 bit era.

Comment: The “%.lf” doesn't work, i still get the wrong value.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to convert large hexadecimals in obj c ?

Comment: The problem is the 64 bits double can not keep full precision of a 128 integer. Just use the 128 bits int defined for your platform.

Comment: It seems clang (the compiler in llvm) supports a __uint128_t - maybe that can lead you to some answer. Using that, you could construct the final value by reading each hex value starting from the right. But no idea how to go from that to a double.